# How do I reset my pointer to a specific array location?

Tags: c++, pointers

I am a brand new programming student, so please forgive my ignorance. My assignment states:

*Write a program that declares an array of 10 integers. Write a loop that accepts 10 values from the keyboard and write another loop that displays the 10 values. Do not use any subscripts within the two loops; use pointers only.*

Here is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
     const int NUM = 10;
     int values[NUM];
     int *p = &values[0];
     int x;
     for(x = 0; x < NUM; ++x, ++p)
     {
         cout << "Enter a value: ";
         cin >> *p;
     }  
     for(x = 0; x < NUM; ++x, ++p)
     {
         cout << *p << "  ";
     }
    return 0;
}
```

I think I know where my problem is. After my first loop, my pointer is at values[10], but I need to get it back to values[0] to display them. How can I do that?

Comment: This sounds more like C than C++ :-)

Comment: @nc3b: I've found out that many colleges say that they teach C++ but actually show C with `cin` and `cout`.

Comment: Yeah that happened in my high school too :-(

Comment: @ohtanya: homework? Please tag it so.

Comment: +1 For including the assignment, showing your work and stating where the problem is.  Also complements for including the `homework` tag.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do exactly as you did first when you assigned `p`:

```
p = &values[0];
```

Besides, arrays are very much like *pointers* (that you can't change) to statically allocated memory. Therefore, the expression `&values[0]` evaluates to the same thing that just `values` does. Consequently,

```
p = &values[0];
```

is the same as

```
p = values;
```

Comment: @ohtanya: No problem. If it works well enough, you can click the check mark under the rating of the answer to accept the answer. :)

Comment: Contrary to common belief, arrays are *not* pointers. In standard language pointers are *modifiable l-values*, while arrays are not. To demonstrate the point, compare two assignments: `p = values;` and `values = p;`. That's where that weird `&array[subscript]` syntax comes from. It works in this case because array name is used as an `r-value`.

Comment: @Nikolai N Fetissov: The only practical difference I can see between `int* const foo` and `int foo[3]` is what `sizeof` yields. Is there any other?

Comment: Try declaring `extern char* buffer;` in a header and then defining `char buffer[256];` in a `.c` file. The compiler will clearly tell you that types are different. I know, it's a bit subtle. If you're interested - pick up a copy of "Expert C Programming: Deep C Secrets" by Peter Van Der Linden - it has a whole chapter about this.

Answer (score 1):

Did your assignment say that you had to print the numbers in order? If not, you could have some fun by printing them in reverse:

```
while (p != values)
{
    cout << *(--p) << " ";
}
```

(Just use this code for learning.)

Answer (score 0):

if the assignment say that you had to print the numbers in order, should modify it as below:

```
for (x = 0; x < NUM; ++x, p++)
{
    cout << *(p-NUM) << "  ";
}
```